# Yii, new controller render does not have the same layout like default

Tags: yii

i dont get why the new controller im making which is rendering a file in an action does not seem to have the same layout in content like yii generates automatically, the site/index, just like contact and about have their content a bit centered in the content, like some padding or margin, but when i make a new controller, it does look the same, looks a bit ugly being stick to the line where the content begins.

heres the new controller im making:

```
<?php

class ToolsController extends CController
{
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // Uncomment the following methods and override them if needed
    /*
    public function filters()
    {
        // return the filter configuration for this controller, e.g.:
        return array(
            'inlineFilterName',
            array(
                'class'=>'path.to.FilterClass',
                'propertyName'=>'propertyValue',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        // return external action classes, e.g.:
        return array(
            'action1'=>'path.to.ActionClass',
            'action2'=>array(
                'class'=>'path.to.AnotherActionClass',
                'propertyName'=>'propertyValue',
            ),
        );
    }
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

and its just rendering this:

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

im missing something?

sorry heres the layout:

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/form.css" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></div>
    </div><!-- header -->

    <div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'nav nav-pills'),
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'Tools', 'url'=>array('/tools/index')),
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div><!-- mainmenu -->
    <?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
            'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
        )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <?php endif?>

    <?php echo $content; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> by My Company.<br/>
        All Rights Reserved.<br/>
        <?php echo Yii::powered(); ?>
    </div><!-- footer -->

</div><!-- page -->

</body>
</ht
```

ml>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix is:

```
public $layout='//layouts/myLayout';
```

Pretty sure you can also set it in the Base Controller also

Comment: thank you, your answer made me notice that my controller was extending from Ccontroller which did not have any column design and the controller from component was calling a column1 which calls the layout with right design, thank you